# Configuring Azure Blob with Grafana deployment with Helm

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, kubernetes-helm, grafana

I am trying to configure Azure Blob as Grafana storage, using Helm for Grafana deployment.

The Azure Blob configuration in the `values.yaml` file I am using is as follows:

```yaml
persistence:
  enabled: true
  size: <volume-size>
  accessMode: <access-mode>.
  storageClassName: <storage-class>
  azureBlob:
    storageAccountName: <storage-account-name>
    containerName: <container-name>
    accountKeySecret: <accountKeySecretName>
```

The deployment does not give errors, but the pod does not start.

I needed to know if the configuration is correct or there is another way to configure the use of the Blob.